# Database query issue

Tags: java, database, date, jdbc

Relatively new to using database and for some reason I can't get this 'execute' to work.

```
statment2.execute("insert into table Value (" + int + "," + date + "," + int + ",'" + string + "')");
```

The error I get is "missing a comma". The date is designated as dates only in that particular field.

I set it up as follows

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setMonth(month);
date.setYear(year);
date.setDate(weekStart); //weekStart is always monday
```

Do I need to use just plain old date or date.toString? I was going to use Calendar but I don't know how to set a DB date using the Calendar object. I didn't see a "gety/m/d" method.

So, is the problem my query or am I improperly using the Date object to set the date in the database?

Edit:

Tried the response, got incorrect format - Expected Date got number.
Tried

```
sqlDate.valueOf(dateString I created)
sqlDate.toString()
sqlDate
```

Using a preparedStatement wouldn't fix this would it? I realize it's supposed to be better for security reasons.

Comment: Few things - 1) depends on the database, every database will handle this differently.  Check out their docs.  2) You should look into JDBC prepared statements instead of creating our own SQL on the fly - you'll end up avoiding some of these types of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to insert values in your query. This has many advantages including avoiding [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issues. If you use PreparedStatement, you will be avoid the errors that you are seeing now. Your code using PreparedStatement would something like this:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      String query = "insert into table (column1,column2,column3,column4) values(?, ?, ?,?)";

      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
      pstmt.setInt(1, 1); 
      pstmt.setDate(2, sqlDate); 
      pstmt.setInt(3, 3); 
      pstmt.setString(3, "test"); 
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //log the error messages log.error(e,e);
      //throw the actual exception upstream
    } finally {
      pstmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }
```

I am not sure what you meant by "DB" date. If you are after the sql date object you can convert a java.util.Date object to a java.sql.Date object this way:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Am I supposed to copy String query = "insert into table (column1,column2,column3,column4) values(?, ?, ?,?) exactly or replace column1 with it's literal name? Sorry for the confusion. Never used prepared statements (going to start though)

Comment: @cphilpot - replace column1 with real name. It's not part of PreparedStatement. Standard SQL.

Comment: Pff, THANKS! Prepared statements are my friend now lol. Will learn how to use them more effectively. :)